# while deploying the war having camel-core pom entry, it gives error: Placeholder [0] doesn't have a value., CI

Tags: apache-camel, deployit

I am using the camel context. On local environment it is working fine and aggregating the message. While on other environment it is giving issue:
`Placeholder [0] doesn't have a value., CI`

We are using deployit for deploying the war file.
There are 2 variables on deploy it but it add 3rd variable with name 0.

I am using the version camel-core version 2.16.1.

Comment: i am using the version camel-core version 2.16.1

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder values are resolved from dictionaries in XL Deploy. If a deployment of the same deployment package works in one environment but fails with a missing placeholder in another, then the cause is most likely a missing placeholder in the dictionary associated with your target environment. Check that the dictionaries are ok and contain all placeholders you expect.

This document describes many of the features of dictionaries and placeholder replacement in XL Deploy: https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/how-to/using-placeholders-in-xl-deploy.html

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i figure out after a lot of inspections that one of my dependencies use '{{0}}' as a placeholder in their messages.properties.

excluding jar files of xldeploy scanning has resolved my issue.

see https://docs.xebialabs.com/v.9.5/xl-deploy/how-to/disable-placeholder-scanning-in-xl-deploy/#disabling-placeholder-scanning-for-one-file-extension-on-a-particular-artifact-type